# Duplication of each line while changing some value within each copy of a line differently in Gnu

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed

I Would like to have each line in a file repeated two times, while in first copy of line any value of 3 be changed into 2, and any value of 4 be changed into 1. And in second copy of each line any value of 3 be changed in to 1, and any value of 4 be changed into 2. I know for duplication I can use awk command:

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<1;i++)print}' input > output
```

But I do not know how to change the values in the way that I have explained

e.g. have each line repeated 2 times:

```
1 000003444
2 334566875
3 000233300
4 222111000
```

becomes:

```
1 000002111
1 000001222
2 221566875
2 112566875
3 000222200
3 000211100
4 222111000
4 222111000
```

Comment: Please proof read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '
  { tmp = $2; gsub("3", "2", $2); gsub("4", "1", $2); print}
  { $2 = tmp; gsub("3", "1", $2); gsub("4", "2", $2); print}
' <file
```

Comment: why if each row be discontinue then this script dose not work properly? for example if row1 :  000003444 be row1 : 0 0 000 3444

Answer (score 0):

A Perl way:

```
$ perl -lane '$i=$F[1]; $F[1]=~s/3/2/g; $F[1]=~s/4/1/g; 
              $i=~s/3/1/g; $i=~s/4/2/g; print "$F[0] $F[1]\n$F[0] $i"' file 
1 000002111
1 000001222
2 221566875
2 112566875
3 000222200
3 000211100
4 222111000
4 222111000
```

First we save the current line as `$i`, then we make the needed substitutions on the current line, then on `$i` and finally we print both the current line (`$_`) and `$i`.